# in C, why can't Double type give you 2^64 like it should?

Tags: c, double, size

If sizeof() gives a 'double' type 8 bytes. 
Then a double type should be able to store 2^64 digits and output that many digits, which is 2^63 = 9.2233720368548E+18.

But I get something weird.

```
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <stdbool.h>
     3  #include <math.h>
     4  
     5  int main(){
     6  double a;
     7  
     8  a = pow(2, 63);
     9  
    10  printf("Size of Double is = %d bytes\n", sizeof(a));
    11  printf("Print full number of 2^63 = %d\n", a);
    12  
    13  return 0;
    14  }
```

Instead the output is

```
Size of Double is = 8 bytes
Print full number of 2^63 = -283958688
```

If you are wondering I am running on 64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Use `%f`to print a double, not `%d`.

Comment: `double` uses **52** bits only (not 64) for the fractional part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: If you use mismatching format specifier and argument type you get *undefined behavior*. The `%d` format is for decimal `int` values.

Comment: *"If sizeof() gives a 'double' type 8 bytes. Then a double type should be able to store 2^64 digits"* - that's definitely *not* how it works. A `double` can very well hold the exact value 2^64, but the number of bytes is *not* the reason. It cannot however hold every value from 2^64 downwards precisely. Learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Oh Ok I see, if I change it to %f, it works. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to learn about the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format for representing floating-point values on binary computers. And perhaps even [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.  A well enabled compiler will warn about `printf("Print full number of 2^63 = %d\n", a);` - faster than posting on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bits can represent up to 2^64 *distinct values*, but (1) C makes no promise to use all 64 bits, and (2) in a floating-point type, not all distinct values represent integers.

Floating-point numbers have to use some of their bits to represent the sign and exponent. For most platforms these days, a 64-bit `double` will have 1 bit for the sign, 11 for the exponent, and 52+1 for the significand.  (The +1 is a most-significant bit of 1. It's not actually present; it's implied by the value of the exponent, and is only assumed to be zero for exponents whose values represent zeros and denormals.)

The end result of the design is that any integer between -2^53 and 2^53 will fit...as will any of those integers multiplied by a sufficiently small power of two, if you can accept some huge caveats. (The catch being, integers over 2^53 forget all but their most significant 53 bits, so for example, you can't add 1 to them to get the next integer.)

As for your `printf`, as the format string represents a different type than you're actually passing, you're running into undefined behavior. But one possible result is that you'll see a decimal version of the int's worth of bits that represents your double, which typically is a very different value than your double represents.